# parallel transport $w$ along $\gamma$: Explicit computation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $S^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 +z^2 =1\}$ . For fixed $t \in [0,1)$ consider the curve $\gamma(t) = (r\cos(t), r\sin(t), \sqrt{1-r^2})$, $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Take $w\in T_{\gamma(0)} S^2$.

I want to compute the parallel transport $w$ along $\gamma$.

---

Naively I know parallel transport $w$ along $\gamma$ as follow:

Let $x(u,v) = \gamma(t)$, then $w = ax_u + b x_v$, then
\begin{align}
  \frac{Dw}{dt} &= \left(a' + \Gamma^1{}_{11} au' + \Gamma^1{}_{12} av' + \Gamma^{1}{}_{12} bu' + \Gamma^1{}_{22} bv' \right) x_u  \\
  & \quad + \left( b'+ \Gamma^2{}_{11} au' + \Gamma^2{}_{12} a v' + \Gamma^2{}_{12} bu' + \Gamma^2{}_{22} bv' \right) x_v 
\end{align}
where $\Gamma^{i}{}_{jk}$ are Chritoffel symobl.

So assuming my Riemannian metric as $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 = r^2dr^2+ r^2\sin^2(\theta) d\theta^2$, I can compute $\Gamma$.

But I am having trouble computing $v$ and corresponding $a,b$. Since $w \in T_{\gamma(0)} S^2$, I guess $w$ should pass through the point $\gamma(0) = (r,0,\sqrt{1-r^2})$

> From $x(u,v) = \gamma(t) = (r\cos(t),r\sin(t),\sqrt{1-r^2})$, Can I idenitfy $(u,v) = (r,t)$? But in this case $u$ is independent of $t$ so my $u'$ all vanishes...

Is my approach correct? (How to formulate $a,b$ out of $\gamma(t)$?) I am familiar with the covariant derivatives acting on tensors, $\nabla_{\mu} x^{\nu} = \partial_{\mu} x^{\nu} + \Gamma^{\nu}{}_{\mu \rho} x^{\rho}$ like in General relativity, but not familiar with these differential geometry notations so having trouble expliict computations.

Comment: [These notes](http://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/GenRel2013/Notes/Geodesics.pdf) show how it is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an exercise one really should do by hand in order to understand all the details involved but let me give you some pointers:

1. Choose some coordinate system $x$ whose image covers (almost all of) the image of the curve $\gamma(t)$. In your case, I would choose
   $$ x(r,t) = \left( r \cos t, r \sin t, \sqrt{1 - r^2} \right) $$
   because then the curve $\gamma$ takes the form $\gamma(t) = x(\mathbf{r},t)$ for a **fixed** $0 < \mathbf{r} < 1$. I will use the bold notation in order to emphasize that $\mathbf{r}$ is fixed (instead of using $r_0$ or something like that which leads to uglier equations).
2. Calculate the components of the metric with respect to this coordinate system. For my choice, you have
   $$ x_r(r,t) = \left( \cos t, \sin t, -\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} \right), \qquad
   x_t(r,t) = \left( -r \sin t, r \cos t, 0 \right), \\
   \left< x_r, x_r \right> = \frac{1}{1 - r^2}, \qquad \left< x_t, x_t \right> = r^2, \qquad \left< x_r, x_t \right> = 0. $$
3. Denote by $v = v(t)$ a parallel vector field along $\gamma$ with $v(0) = w$ and write it in terms of the basis for the tangent space induced by your coordinate system as
   $$v(t) = a(t) x_r|_{\gamma(t)} + b(t) x_t|_{\gamma(t)} = a(t) x_r(\mathbf{r}, t)+ b(t) x_t (\mathbf{r}, t). $$
   You need to solve the equation $\frac{Dv}{dt}$ which will give you a system of first order differential equations in terms of the components $a(t),b(t)$.
4. In order to compute $\frac{Dv}{dt}$, you can compute the Christoffel symbols with respect to the coordinate system $x$, express $\gamma'(t)$ in terms of $x_r,x_t$ (we have $\gamma'(t) = x_t(\mathbf{r},t)$) and use the formula for the covariant derivative. Alternatively, a faster method in this case is to calculate the regular derivative $v'(t)$ of
   $$ v(t) = a(t) x_r(\mathbf{r},t) + b(t) x_t(\mathbf{r},t) $$
   and project it orthogonally onto the tangent space $T_{\gamma(t)}S^2$. The final result is
   $$ \frac{Dv}{dt} = \left( a'(t) + \mathbf{r}(\mathbf{r}^2 - 1) b(t) \right) x_r|_{\gamma(t)} + \left( b'(t) + \frac{a(t)}{\mathbf{r}} \right) x_t|_{\gamma(t)}. $$
5. The equation $\frac{Dv}{dt} = 0$ translates into the system of equations
   $$ a'(t) = \mathbf{r} \left( 1 - \mathbf{r}^2 \right) b(t), \qquad b'(t) = -\frac{a(t)}{\mathbf{r}}. $$
   Plug one of the equations into the other to get a second order equation for $a(t)$ which you can easily solve. Do the same for $b(t)$. Writing everything in terms of the initial conditions $a(0),b(0)$, you will get
   $$ a(t) = \mathbf{r} \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} \sin \left( \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} t \right) + a(0) \cos \left( \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} t \right), \\
   b(t) = -\frac{a(0)}{\mathbf{r} \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2}} \sin \left( \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} t \right) + b(0) \cos \left( \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} t \right).$$
6. Finally, do some sanity checks. For example, the initial condition $w = \gamma'(0)$ corresponds to $a(0) = 0, b(0) = 1$. In this case,
   $$ v(t) = \mathbf{r} \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} \sin \left( \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} t \right) x_r \left( \mathbf{r}, t \right) + \cos \left( \sqrt{1 - \mathbf{r}^2} t \right) x_t \left( \mathbf{r}, t \right). $$
   You can see that if $\mathbf{r} \in \{ 0, 1\}$ then $v(t)$ is constant which is expected because when $\mathbf{r} = 1$ the curve $\gamma(t)$ is a geodesic while if $\mathbf{r} = 0$ the curve $\gamma(t)$ is constant. When $0 < \mathbf{r} < 1$, you can see that the cosine of the angle between $v(2\pi)$ and $v(0)$ is $\cos \left( \sqrt{ 1 - \mathbf{r}^2} 2\pi \right)$ so as $\mathbf{r}$ gets closer to $0$ (and the curve $\gamma$ gets closer and closer to the north pole), $v(0)$ rotates almost completely around the tangent $v'(t)$.

Comment: WOW! Thanks for your big effort! 

I have one question about $\frac{Dv}{dt}$. 

From $v$, I compute $\frac{dv}{dt} = (\frac{a(t)}{r} + b'(t)) x_t + a'(t) x_r + b(t) (-r\cos(t), -r\sin(t),0)$ and now I want to perform projection onto $T_{\gamma(t)}S^2$ and obtain your result. It seems my $(-r\cos(t), - r\sin(t), 0)$ becomes $r(r^2-1) x_r$ after projection . But I don't know how. Can you explain me more about this process?

Comment: never mind I figure it out.  Its noting but $\operatorname{proj}_{T_{\gamma} S^2} \frac{dv}{dt}$ and after orthogonal projection I obtained your result. 

One more question about computing $\frac{Dv}{dt}$ :  Is $\frac{Dv}{dt} = \operatorname{proj}_{T_{\gamma(t)} S^2} \frac{dv}{dt}$ holds for any other case?  or holds only in this special case? [If I replace $S^2$ by any other arbitrary manifold $M$, does this formula still holds? ]

Comment: @phy_math: Whenever $M$ is a manifold which sits inside some ambient Riemannian manifold $N$ (in our case, $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard inner product) **and** the Riemannian metric on $M$ is the one induced from $N$, the covariant derivative on $M$ will be the orthogonal projection onto the tangent space of the covariant derivative on $N$. In our case, on $N = \mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard inner product, the covariant derivative is just the regular derivative.